# Move Pound £ symbol from after a number to before it

Tags: php

My string is as follow :

```
<b>100£</b> was £160
```

As you can see, the `100£` is wrong it should be `£100`.

Does someone know how to move (in PHP) the first £ symbol before the first number, without touching the second one (which is correct) ?

Thank you so much

Comment: Where's the PHP that builds this? If you just have `<b>100£</b>` in the code it is pretty simple, copy + paste.

Comment: See [`money_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php).

Comment: Thank you Alex. I probably didn't explain my problem properly.  It it was only a matter of copy and paste I'd not be asking about it :/ The string I'm showing here is already built and stored in mysql. I only have this Mysql db without any PHP. Now I need to move the first  pound sign so the price is properly written, probably with a regex but I have no idea how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
$re = '/(\d{1,})/m';
$str = '<b>100£</b> was £160';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
if(count($matches)>0 && isset($matches[0][0]) && isset($matches[1][0])) {
    echo(sprintf('<b>£%d</b> was £%d', $matches[0][0], $matches[1][0]));
}
```